# Intel Advanced-N 6235 wireless monitor mode problem

Tags: security, wifi, intel

As far as I know, iwlwifi drivers (and this particular wireless card) support monitor mode. The only requirement is to install the latest driver from http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/iwlwifi (in this case, *iwlwifi-6000g2b-ucode-18.168.6.1* will do the trick).

The scenario is the following:

BackTrack LiveCD booted in a laptop with this wireless card. The wireless does not work until the above driver is downloaded and loaded into the kernel via `modprobe`. After that, wireless do work (can connect to different networks, being stable, etc).

However, when trying to activate monitor mode (`airmon-ng start wlan0`), it will never activate *mon0* (monitor interface). I have some experience on this with an Alfa 1W and I was expecting a similar result with this card, but it seems that I am missing something, or maybe the drivers does not support monitor mode (using the wrong ones?).

I have been googling around but I did not found any specific solution, so hopefully someone can suggest some workaround!